# How to find top 10 products with greatest price increase within each category

Tags: r

I am just starting to learn to use R. How can I find top 10 products with greatest month-to-month price increase within each product category?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I don't think this is a tool request. More information is needed though

Comment: First step is to **have data** on products with their prices by month. If you've got that, show a small sample, or simulate a small sample, and we can start to help!

Comment: @Gregor:For simplicity let's say we are looking for the top2, not top10; Headings: Category Product PrevMonthPrice CurrentMonthPrice:

Food,Orange,5,10;
Clothing,Shirt,25,35;
Food,Apple,2,4;
Clothing,Hat,25,15;
Food,Soup,4.5,3;
Clothing,Coat,150,200;
Food,Meat,9,11;
Clothing,Scarf,20,25;
Food,Rice,8,12;
Clothing,Shoes,150,125;

Comment: @Pedja For simplicity, please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32981851/edit) to include any relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use package dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text="
Category, Product, PrevMonthPrice, CurrentMonthPrice
Food,Orange,5,10
Clothing,Shirt,25,35
Food,Apple,2,4
Clothing,Hat,25,15
Food,Soup,4.5,3
Clothing,Coat,150,200
Food,Meat,9,11
Clothing,Scarf,20,25
Food,Rice,8,12
Clothing,Shoes,150,125", sep=",", header=TRUE)

df %>% 
        mutate(increase=CurrentMonthPrice-PrevMonthPrice) %>% 
        group_by(Category) %>%
        arrange(-increase) %>% 
        top_n(2)


Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: Category [2]

  Category Product PrevMonthPrice CurrentMonthPrice increase
    (fctr)  (fctr)          (dbl)             (int)    (dbl)
1 Clothing    Coat            150               200       50
2 Clothing   Shirt             25                35       10
3     Food  Orange              5                10        5
4     Food    Rice              8                12        4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the same result with "pure" R:

```
df$increase=df$CurrentMonthPrice-df$PrevMonthPrice
top=2
res=lapply(split(df,df$Category), function(xd){
  xd[with(xd,order(-increase)),][1:top,]
})

do.call(rbind,res)
```